# EditorBrowsableAttribute state doesn't work in same assembly

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, intellisense, intellicode

Is there a way to set the state of System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute?

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

It doesn't work from the same assembly (from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netcore-3.1)), someone know how to "fix" that? Or create a custom attribute that work with intellisense?

Comment: Still doesn't seem to be possible: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/51269